# undefined reference errors: Compiling HPL Benchmark

Tags: c, benchmarking, hpc, blas, linpack

I have been trying to compile HPL benchmark and I think after solving many problems I have come to a halt. I would appreciate help.

I have installed the cblas and mpi already:

Now I just get the HPL_* related undefined references in linking.

Something like:

```
HPL_pddriver.c:(.text.startup+0x255): undefined reference to `HPL_grid_init'
HPL_pddriver.c:(.text.startup+0x27d): undefined reference to `HPL_grid_info'
HPL_pddriver.c:(.text.startup+0x42b): undefined reference to `HPL_pdpanrlN'
HPL_pddriver.c:(.text.startup+0x460): undefined reference to `HPL_pdrpanrlN'
HPL_pddriver.c:(.text.startup+0x47e): undefined reference to `HPL_pdupdateNN'
HPL_pddriver.c:(.text.startup+0x57d): undefined reference to `HPL_pdpanrlT'
....
.... and so on
```

Even when I manually execute the compiler command like the following it doesn't work:

```
/home/user/work/installs/mpich_installed/bin/mpicc  -DHPL_CALL_CBLAS -I/home/user/hpl/include -I/home/user/hpl/include/Linux_My_CBLAS -I/home/user/work/HPC_AI/benchmarking/cblas/CBLAS/include -I/home/user/work/installs/mpich_installed/include -L/home/user/hpl/lib/Linux_My_CBLAS -L/home/user/work/HPC_AI/benchmarking/cblas/CBLAS/lib/ -L/home/user/work/installs/mpich_installed/lib/ -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -funroll-loops -lmpi -lcblas_LINUX -lhpl -o /home/user/hpl/bin/Linux_My_CBLAS/xhpl HPL_pddriver.o         HPL_pdinfo.o           HPL_pdtest.o
```

Here is my Make.arch file (minus the license header):

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - shell --------------------------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
SHELL        = /bin/sh
#
CD           = cd
CP           = cp
LN_S         = ln -s
MKDIR        = mkdir
RM           = /bin/rm -f
TOUCH        = touch
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Platform identifier ------------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
ARCH         = Linux_My_CBLAS
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - HPL Directory Structure / HPL library ------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
TOPdir       = $(HOME)/hpl
INCdir       = $(TOPdir)/include
BINdir       = $(TOPdir)/bin/$(ARCH)
LIBdir       = $(TOPdir)/lib/$(ARCH)
#
HPLlib       = $(LIBdir)/libhpl.a
HPLlib_PATH  = -L$(LIBdir)
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Message Passing library (MPI) --------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# MPinc tells the  C  compiler where to find the Message Passing library
# header files,  MPlib  is defined  to be the name of  the library to be
# used. The variable MPdir is only used for defining MPinc and MPlib.
#
MPdir        = /home/user/work/installs/mpich_installed
MPinc        = -I$(MPdir)/include
MPlib        = -L$(MPdir)/lib/
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Linear Algebra library (BLAS or VSIPL) -----------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# LAinc tells the  C  compiler where to find the Linear Algebra  library
# header files,  LAlib  is defined  to be the name of  the library to be
# used. The variable LAdir is only used for defining LAinc and LAlib.
#
LAdir        = /home/user/work/HPC_AI/benchmarking/cblas/CBLAS
LAinc        = -I$(LAdir)/include
LAlib        = -L$(LAdir)/lib/
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - F77 / C interface --------------------------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# You can skip this section  if and only if  you are not planning to use
# a  BLAS  library featuring a Fortran 77 interface.  Otherwise,  it  is
# necessary  to  fill out the  F2CDEFS  variable  with  the  appropriate
# options.  **One and only one**  option should be chosen in **each** of
# the 3 following categories:
#
# 1) name space (How C calls a Fortran 77 routine)
#
# -DAdd_              : all lower case and a suffixed underscore  (Suns,
#                       Intel, ...),                           [default]
# -DNoChange          : all lower case (IBM RS6000),
# -DUpCase            : all upper case (Cray),
# -DAdd__             : the FORTRAN compiler in use is f2c.
#
# 2) C and Fortran 77 integer mapping
#
# -DF77_INTEGER=int   : Fortran 77 INTEGER is a C int,         [default]
# -DF77_INTEGER=long  : Fortran 77 INTEGER is a C long,
# -DF77_INTEGER=short : Fortran 77 INTEGER is a C short.
#
# 3) Fortran 77 string handling
#
# -DStringSunStyle    : The string address is passed at the string loca-
#                       tion on the stack, and the string length is then
#                       passed as  an  F77_INTEGER  after  all  explicit
#                       stack arguments,                       [default]
# -DStringStructPtr   : The address  of  a  structure  is  passed  by  a
#                       Fortran 77  string,  and the structure is of the
#                       form: struct {char *cp; F77_INTEGER len;},
# -DStringStructVal   : A structure is passed by value for each  Fortran
#                       77 string,  and  the  structure is  of the form:
#                       struct {char *cp; F77_INTEGER len;},
# -DStringCrayStyle   : Special option for  Cray  machines,  which  uses
#                       Cray  fcd  (fortran  character  descriptor)  for
#                       interoperation.
#
F2CDEFS      =
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - HPL includes / libraries / specifics -------------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
HPL_INCLUDES = -I$(INCdir) -I$(INCdir)/$(ARCH) $(LAinc) $(MPinc)
HPL_LIBS     = $(HPLlib_PATH) $(LAlib) $(MPlib)
#
# - Compile time options -----------------------------------------------
#
# -DHPL_COPY_L           force the copy of the panel L before bcast;
# -DHPL_CALL_CBLAS       call the cblas interface;
# -DHPL_CALL_VSIPL       call the vsip  library;
# -DHPL_DETAILED_TIMING  enable detailed timers;
#
# By default HPL will:
#    *) not copy L before broadcast,
#    *) call the BLAS Fortran 77 interface,
#    *) not display detailed timing information.
#
HPL_OPTS     = -DHPL_CALL_CBLAS
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
HPL_DEFS     = $(F2CDEFS) $(HPL_OPTS) $(HPL_INCLUDES)
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# - Compilers / linkers - Optimization flags ---------------------------
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
CC           = $(MPdir)/bin/mpicc
CCNOOPT      = $(HPL_DEFS)
CCFLAGS      = $(HPL_DEFS) -fomit-frame-pointer -O3 -funroll-loops -lmpi -lcblas_LINUX -lhpl
#
# On some platforms,  it is necessary  to use the Fortran linker to find
# the Fortran internals used in the BLAS library.
#
LINKER       = $(MPdir)/bin/mpicc
LINKFLAGS    = $(CCFLAGS)
#
ARCHIVER     = ar
ARFLAGS      = r
RANLIB       = echo
#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Does it help to put the `-l...` options after the object file on the command line?

Comment: @thebusybee: It most likely would.

Comment: @alk So let's see if Bibrak tries it. ;-)

Comment: @thebusybee could you please elaborate?

Comment: @thebusybee I placed them at the end of the command but still the same problem

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the new command line that gives you the error. My crystal ball can't see it currently.